# Problem with display of LaTeX-Webquiz

Tags: html, make4ht

As I am new to the [WebQuiz](https://ctan.org/pkg/webquiz?lang=en) package I am struggling with the correct display of a quiz. I would be super glad about any help as I would like to use WebQuiz for maths university and high school teaching.

I have gone through the webquiz manual instructions and can actually compile a quiz without getting any errors. Just when I look at the quiz html page (either locally or if I upload it to my webspace) I get this result: [image]

Buttons, etc. work, it's only that there are these strange tags and all the LaTeX-elements are not displayed properly.

When I just run `make4ht` on the quiz it is properly compiled:

[image]

I have tried webquiz with both TeXLive and MiKTeX - with both installations I stumble upon the same problem.

Big thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this was caused by an upstream bug in LuaXML related to handling of CDATA entries. Version 0.1m (2020-07-19) of LuaXML fixes the problem. The updated LuaXML package is now available from ctan. If you are using texlive then you can install the update with `tlmgr update luaxml`, or `sudo tlmgr update luaxml`. If you are using MiKTeX then you can update the LuaXML package using the MiKTeX console.

Comment: I updated the package as suggested. Now, I stumble upon [this](https://github.com/AndrewAtLarge/WebQuiz/issues/11) bug. I guess you haven't uploaded the fix for this bug yet.

Comment: @fehl-x  No, I have not uploaded this fix yet. This problem happens mainly when people mistype the name of their TeX file, so it is not overly serious although, granted, it is annoying. The next update remove the requirement of installing local css and javscript files so that it will no longer necessary to initialise the package, which many people find painful. The new code is working but I still need to update the manual. Unfortunately, I have no time for this at the moment due to my work commitments but I will try and push the updated version out soon.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much! I've figured it out and now it works: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cm8M.png (It only seems there are some space lines missing.)

Answer (score 1):

I have just found out, that this issue seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/AndrewAtLarge/WebQuiz/issues/9) in the WebQuiz package itself.

Comment: Not so much as a bug as an compatibility with recent changes in tex4ht/make4ht. I will update when I get some time,

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for your response and your commitment, @Andrew !